# Wordpress function to get top level category of a post?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am trying to find the top most category of a post.  I tried finding any WP builtin functions but failed.

For example I have categories like this.

```
Parent
     sub-1
          sub-2
```

And I have a post in sub-2.  So with the ID of sub-2, I am trying to find the ID of top most category which is named "Parent" in this example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I ended up building my own function to get the top most level category.

```
// function to get the top level category object
// Usage - $top_cat = get_top_category();
// echo $top_cat->slug;

function get_top_category() {
    $cats = get_the_category(); // category object
    $top_cat_obj = array();

    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent == 0) {
            $top_cat_obj[] = $cat;  
        }
    }
    $top_cat_obj = $top_cat_obj[0];
    return $top_cat_obj;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the array to put the top category object in. A string var should do it :-)

Comment: See this answer. It is a flag that can be passed to get_terms(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113247/wordpress-show-only-top-level-categories

Comment: @GhostToast But you can not pass a post to get_terms()

Comment: If the post is in "sub-2" category, it will only return one category. You need to use get_the_terms

Answer (score 1):

Look at this helpful script: 
[Get Top Level Parent Category Id Of a Single Post](https://isabelcastillo.com/get-top-level-parent-category-single)

And you can change this part:

```
$catParent = $cat->cat_ID;
```

To

```
$catParent = $cat->name;
```

To get the name of the top level category

Answer (score 0):

For the ones having problems with this method I found a simple solution, probably not the best one in terms of efficiency.
To get the top level category parent from post/product page

Usage:

```
global $post;
$terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'orderby' => 'parent', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $main_term = $terms[0];
    $root_cat_id = get_top_category($main_term->term_id);
```

Function:

```
function get_top_category ($catid) {
$cat_parent_id=0;
while ($catid!=null & $catid!=0) {
    $current_term = get_term($catid); 
    $catid = $current_term->parent; 
    if($catid!=null & $catid!=0){
        $cat_parent_id = $catid;
    }else{
        $cat_parent_id = $current_term->term_id;
    }
}
return $cat_parent_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent'  => 0 //this parameter is important for top level category
    )
);
```

Comment: Post some explanation for your solution, rather than just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

The good answer today is:

```
$cats = get_the_terms( false, 'category' );
$topcat = array();

foreach($cats as $cat)
{
    if ($cat->parent == 0)
        $topcat = $cat;  
}
```

Because get_the_category wont return "sub1" category if the post is just in "sub2", even if "sub2" is a sub category of "sub1".
And you can get the cat ID with get_cat_ID...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $top_category = get_the_category_list(',');
    echo $top_category;
```

Answer (score -2):

I needed parent ID and this worked nice and simple for me:

```
$topcat = get_the_category();
echo $topcat[0]->category_parent;
```

Comment: This only shows the parent of the current category, not the top level category (two levels up in this instance)