# Wordpress: Show only TOP level categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using this bit of code:

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'style' => 'none',
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'hide_empty' => 0,
  'depth' => 1,
  'title_li' => ''
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

What I am trying to do is to list only top level categories. When I am using this code I am getting all of them not just level one. Can someone help me?

Comment: There is no depth argument for get_categories() -http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories the depth argument is used in wp_list_categories() - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no `depth` argument for `get_categories()`, you should try :

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
);
```

> **`parent`** :
>   (integer) Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category identified by its ID. This does NOT work like the 'child_of' parameter. There is no default for this parameter. [In 2.8.4]

Read more : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Get_only_top_level_categories

Comment: How to display only one level subcategory?
for eg : i want to hide child categories of first level subcategory

Comment: Thanks soju , its a great help :)

Answer (score 2):

soju post is very helpful, for to get category only 1 level subcategory  we should just pass the category id that has subcategories . But if the subcategory have no any post then it doesnot shows but subcategory subcategory consist the post so add 'hide_empty' => 0, in the above condition it will look like

```
$args = array(
'taxonomy' => 'categories',
'parent' => 7,
'hide_empty' => 0,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script to get top level category names from within the loop. This will include top level categories that just have a child category checked, and are not explicitly checked themselves.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $topcats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent != 0) $cat = get_term($cat->parent, 'category');
        $topcats[$cat->term_id] = '<a href="/category/' . $cat->slug . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
    }
    echo implode(', ', $topcats);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function allows you to choose which category level... so in your case you'd choose level 0 and it would look like `<?php display_cat_level(0,true); ?>` in your single.php theme file

https://github.com/pjeaje/code-snippets/blob/gh-pages/display%20a%20specific%20category%20level%20of%20a%20post%20inside%20the%20loop

```
// http://wpquestions.com/question/showChronoLoggedIn/id/9333
// display a specific category level of a post inside the loop
// USAGE: <?php display_cat_level(X,true); ?> where TRUE = linked | false/empty = not linked
function get_level($category, $level = 0)
{
    if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
        return $level;
    } else {
        $level++;
        $category = get_category($category->category_parent);
        return get_level($category, $level);
    }
}

function display_cat_level( $level = 0 , $link=false){

    $cats = get_the_category( );
    if( $cats ){
        foreach($cats as $cat){
            $current_cat_level = get_level($cat);
            if( $current_cat_level  == $level ){
                if($link==true) {
                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">'.$cat->name."</a><br />";
                } else {
                    echo $cat->name."<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```