# WordPress: How do I show the parent category in the post meta?

Tags: wordpress, parent, categories, meta

I have a WP site here: http://www.undergroundsound.com.au

As you can see each post on the front page says "Posted in 'child categories'".  I would like it to say something like "Posted in 'parent category' - 'child categories'".

This is the code that needs to be edited, in content.php:

```
<?php printf( __( 'Posted in %1$s', 'underground_sound' ), $categories_list ); ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you for reading.

Comment: Show use what you've tried up to now.

Comment: Where are you getting $categories_list?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean.  That code is in content.php, which displays the posts on the front page.

Comment: I've amended my answer below for you with the code you need to add/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (taken from this post: [Wordpress function to get top level category of a post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823452/wordpress-function-to-get-top-level-category-of-a-post)):

put this in your functions.php file at the bottom before the closing ?> tag

```
function get_top_category() {
    $cats = get_the_category(); // category object
    $top_cat_obj = array();

    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent == 0) {
            $top_cat_obj[] = $cat;  
        }
    }
    $top_cat_obj = $top_cat_obj[0];
    return $top_cat_obj;
}
```

Amend your content.php:

```
<?php $top_cat = get_top_category();?>

<?php printf( __( 'Posted in %1$s', 'underground_sound' ), $top_cat->slug .' - '.$categories_list ); ?>
```

Comment: That simply displays the parent category, but I can't insert that like it is in to the area of code I need to.

Comment: Ok, where is the code that displays the child categories at the moment? If you post it I will update it for you

Comment: Sorry your edited version doesn't work.  You can see the result here: http://www.designated.net.au/testbed/undergroundsound/

Comment: The parent category doesn't display and there is a PHP error at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I also included the last curly bracket you left out of the code for functions.php.  For some reason my functions php has no ?> at the end, I wonder why.

Comment: The error is gone but the parent category isn't displaying.  It displays if I mark it in the post but it also displays in the child categories.  You're not supposed to mark parent categories in WordPress, just child categories.  Also it is just text, not a link when it displays.